# Error in R survival analysis using for loop for events

Tags: r, for-loop, events, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have moderate experience with R. I am trying to run a Cox regression with a for loop using the survival package. My dataframe (df1) contains multiple health outcomes as "events". I want to regress "FA_low" on health outcomes and time, adding age sex and pc1-pc10 as covariates.

This is a subset of the dataframe (df1) that I generated using `dput(df1[1:2, -c(3,4)]`:

```
structure(list(id = c("1000016", "1000028"), FA_low = c("1", 
"1"), sex = c("F", "F"), age = c(56L, 66L), pc1 = c(125.117, 
-9.61593), pc2 = c(-67.8548, 5.7494), pc3 = c(57.7852, -1.71108
), pc4 = c(7.68796, -4.73091), pc5 = c(0.445619, -3.22911), pc6 = c(2.93785, 
-0.0760323), pc7 = c(7.02217, 2.93723), pc8 = c(4.40888, 0.982279
), pc9 = c(-0.704416, -0.161818), pc10 = c(5.46248, -0.579022
), time = c(5, 5), '250' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '250.2' = c(FALSE, 
FALSE), '250.23' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '272' = c(NA, FALSE), '272.1' = c(NA, 
FALSE), '272.11' = c(NA, FALSE), '274.1' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '278' = c(FALSE, 
FALSE), '278.1' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '351' = c(FALSE, FALSE), `'401' = c(NA, 
FALSE), '401.1' = c(NA, FALSE), '411' = c(NA, FALSE), '411.4' = c(NA, 
FALSE), '411.8' = c(NA, FALSE), '454' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '454.1' = c(FALSE, 
FALSE), '512.7' = c(FALSE, FALSE), '550' = c(NA, FALSE), '550.2' = c(NA, 
FALSE), '550.4' = c(NA, FALSE), '740' = c(NA, FALSE), '740.1' = c(NA, 
FALSE), '907' = c(FALSE, FALSE)), row.names = 1:2, class = "data.frame")
```

Structure:

```
'data.frame':   426295 obs. of  41 variables:
 $ id             : chr  "1000016" "1000028" "1000033" "1000042" ...
 $ FA_low         : chr  "1" "1" "0" "0" ...
 $ sex            : chr  "F" "F" "F" "F" ...
 $ age            : int  56 66 64 50 69 63 42 41 62 64 ...
 $ pc1            : num  125.12 -9.62 -12.53 -12.29 -11.33
 $ time           : num  5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
 $ 250            : logi  FALSE FALSE FALSE NA FALSE FALSE ..
```

.

When I run my analysis without a loop for each health outcome separately, it works fine. When I try to create a for loop with the health outcomes as iterations as follows:

`for(i in 1:24){`
`df.model<-na.omit(df1[c(1:17,17+i)])`

`cox.mod <- coxph( Surv(time, i) ~ FA_low + age + sex + pc1 + pc2 + pc3 + pc4 + pc5 + pc6 + pc7 + pc8 + pc9 + pc10, data = df.model)`

`cox1 <- summary(cox.mod)`

I get the following error:
`Error in Surv(time, i) : Time and status are different lengths`

The number of observations in these columns is the same. I am inclined to think that my for loop does not match the way the Surv() function works. I went through the documentation for the Surv() package but I still can't solve this. I have seen questions and answers regarding for loops for 'time' but not events.  How do I create a for loop that works with iterations for events in this survival analysis?

Comment: I'd like to try to help you answer your question. Are you able to share example data? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example

Comment: I just noticed you are using `na.omit()` to define your modelling dataset; this may lead to your error. What happens when you leave `NA` in your data?

Comment: Thanks for this. I have made edits to the original post showing a subset of my dataframe. I also tried running the code without na.omit() as you suggested but I still get the same error...

Comment: Try placing `print(i)` in the first line of your loop and investigating the column (iteration) that gives the error.

Comment: Try replacing `Surv(time, i)` with `Surv(time, df.model[[i]])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the error you're seeing is related to how `Surv()` expects its arguments to be formatted within `coxph()`. It expects column names as variables rather than their position (i.e. your use of `i`). One solution is to call values of each `status` directly. Check this out:

```
library(survival)
#> Warning: package 'survival' was built under R version 4.0.5

test1 <- list(time=c(4,3,1,1,2,2,3), 
              status=c(1,1,1,0,1,1,0), 
              x=c(0,2,1,1,1,0,0), 
              sex=c(0,0,0,0,1,1,1),
              status2=c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE)) 

## This works

coxph(Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ x + strata(sex), data = test1)
#> 
#>     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
#> x 0.8023    2.2307   0.8224 0.976 0.329
#> 
#> Likelihood ratio test=1.09  on 1 df, p=0.2971
#> n= 7, number of events= 5

## This doesn't work

coxph(Surv(time, 2) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
#> Error in Surv(time, 2): Time and status are different lengths

## This works

coxph(Surv(time, test1[[2]]) ~ x + strata(sex), test1)
#> Call:
#> coxph(formula = Surv(time, test1[[2]]) ~ x + strata(sex), data = test1)
#> 
#>     coef exp(coef) se(coef)     z     p
#> x 0.8023    2.2307   0.8224 0.976 0.329
#> 
#> Likelihood ratio test=1.09  on 1 df, p=0.2971
#> n= 7, number of events= 5
Created on 2021-09-01 by the reprex package (v2.0.1)
```

Note that in my example (from the survival documentation), `test1` is a list. You may need to use `df.model[,i]` or convert `df.model` to a list. Also, should `i` in `Surv()` always be `18`, as the 18th column contains your event data in every iteration of `df.model`?

Comment: Thank you @Skaqqs, this makes sense and the error went when I went for `(Surv(time, df.model[[i+17]])` . However, this only works for the first iteration - i.e. when `i <- 1`. For the rest of the iterations, I am now getting this error: `Error in df.model[[i + 17]] : subscript out of bounds` . The error remains even when I convert `df.model` to a list or when I use `df.model[,i+17]`...

Comment: Oh my bad! I think instead of `df.model[[i + 17]]`, you want `df.model[[18]]`? That is, every `df.model` will have 18 columns, and the 18th column is your event, and your even varies at each iteration of the loop.